# Cache/Save Images from other Domain or something (NGINX)

Tags: nginx

is there a chance to save URLs with Images from other sites?

We show Images directly from the URL of another site (completely different server).
Its not our server and not our site where we get that images from.

Is there a way to save that images into cache or anything to load our site with there images faster? Most time our site is already loading and some images of them are not loaded fast enaugh